# Fonts not found (baskervald)

Tags: fonts, texlive, linux, kpfonts

I'm trying to use Baskerville font using

```
\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}
```

pdflatex fails with the following error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 ybvr8r
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for ybvr8r.
mktexpk: perhaps ybvr8r is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
)
(see the transcript file for additional information)

!pdfTeX error: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file ybvr8r): Font ybvr8r at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The document compiles if I remove `\usepackage{kpfonts,baskervald}`. I am using texlive in arch linux (I installed [texlive-most](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/texlive-most/)).

I tried a few things but could not get it working.
The file seem to be installed in the texmf tree:

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/arkandis/baskervald/ybvr8r.tfm
```

and is detected by `kpsewhich`:

```
$ kpsewhich ybvr8r.tfm
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/arkandis/baskervald/ybvr8r.tfm
```

The error suggests that the map file might be missing, I don't really know what it is, but I tried this (following baskervaldadf documentation):

```
sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=ybv.map
```

which fails with:

```
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap: top config file /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg has not been read. at /usr/bin/updmap line 1488.
```

The file `/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg` exists.

I'm stuck here... I suspect that there is a problem with the fact that some files are present in both the `/usr/share/texmf-dist` directory and the `/etc/texmf` directory. For example there is a ls-R in both. The one in `/usr/share/texmf-dist` has baskervald (but only `.afm` files, so not `ybvr8r.tfm`) but the one in `/etc/texmf` doesn't. But I have no idea if that's really a problem...

I have the Baskervald ADF font in `/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/arkandis/baskervald` in `.pfb` and `.pfm` format. There is no `ybvr8r.pfb` though, but that seems normal looking at the package on CTAN.

As @UlrikeFischer suggested, adding `\pdfmapfile{=ybv.map}` solves the problem, but now pdflatex is complaining about an other missing font (jkpsy), which is also present in my texlive installation. So the problem is not really solved. There seems to be a problem of configuration of my texlive...

Running `sudo texconfig-sys` reveals that `updmap.cfg` is not found, although it is there `/etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg`

As @cfr pointed out, it is a problem of the arch linux texlive package, already mentioned here:https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=78899

There is an additional white space in updmap.cfg at the Map euler.map line. Removing the additional white space, running texconfig-sys and updmap-sys solved the problem!

Thanks!

EDIT: added some info to answer the comments

Comment: Tfms are font metrics, not fonts. Do you actually have the baskervald fonts installed?

Comment: Exactly what is texlive-most? There is a reason why I generally do not recommend getting latex from a Linux distribution, their repacking makes things so much more confusing.

Comment: In the kpsewhich search for tfm, go back up the tree and down the type1 branch and see if you can find the baskervald pfb files.

Comment: Also, you should probably change the title of your question, as system font is misleading in this case. That normally refers to a font from the operating system. Here your are dealing with a font from latex that are not picked up.

Comment: Add `\pdfmapfile{=ybv.map}` to your document. Does it work then?

Comment: @daelif: I added information to my post to answer your questions (yes baskervald is installed and texlive-most is a group of package)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yes it works! but now it's complaining about an other font which is also present. It seems like my texlive installation is not properly configured...

Comment: It is normal to have multiple `ls-R`s. TeX uses them to find things quickly. Does `~/.texlive2016` exist? If so, delete it. (Or rename it, if you prefer.) There should be no `8r.pfb`. That is normal. It is not normal to have to use `\pdfmapfile{+ybv.map}`. It seems that your `updmap` configuration is not correct. Either `updmap-sys` was not run correctly or something is masking the system-wide configuration. Removing `~/.texlive2016` should address the second issue. Does `pacman.log` contain any errors/warnings related to installation/update of TeX Live? What does `kpsewhich updmap.cfg` give?

Comment: I am not familiar with Arch's packaging. (I always use vanilla TeX Live from upstream.)  I can't figure out how `texlive` Arch packages update the formats and map files.

Comment: @cfr there is a `~/.texlive`, but removing it doesn't solve the problem. 
`pacman.log` does not report any warnings/errors but there is a message : `>>> updmap custom entries should go into /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap-local.cfg`.
`kpsewhich updmap.cfg` returns nothing... but there is a `updmap.cfg` in `/etc/texmf/web2c/`

Comment: Apparently, Arch uses `~/.texlive` rather than `~/.texliveYYYY`. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live_FAQ. It isn't clear to me if pacman's message means: you have to add the maps for *these* fonts yourself or if it just means, you have to add the maps for any non-pacman-installed fonts. I'd assume the latter, because the former would be crazy. I would very strongly recommend installing from upstream and ditching Arch's TeX Live.

Comment: See https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=78899. The thread is old but scroll down to the 2017-04 posts, though I'd have assumed the bug would be fixed by now.

Comment: @cfr, thanks! there was indeed additional white space in `updmap.cfg` at the `Map euler.map` line. Removing the additional white space, running `texconfig-sys` and `updmap-sys` solved the problem!

Comment: Please don't put answers in questions. It makes things very confusing. Ask somebody to answer or, if you solved the problem yourself, answer yourself. That way, other people with the same question can tell the question got an answer. If the answer is in the question, the question appears unanswered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved in comments, is due to a distro packaging bug and the answer has been edited into the question.

Comment: @AlexB Thanks, I have voted to close it. Since it is a bug in Arch's packaging, it isn't likely to be of much help to future users. (Well, assuming Arch fixes the bug, but that's an easy fix and such things usually happen very quickly once problems are reported.)

Comment: @cfr To clarify: the pdfmapfile code wasn't meant as a solution but to test if the problem is in the updmap configuration.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I know. I wasn't sure if that would be clear to the OP, though.